# textView setText() Null Pointer Exception [Single Activity Application]

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

The simple app with just one activity is creating problems with finding the layout's TextView and showing the same as null. Kindly debug the same why the app is crashing on clicking the submit button. I tried many solutions in Stack Overflow and many solutions say that the view might be located outside the activity specified, but here the only one activity is there. So research didn't help me, and now I'm left with the fellow developers who could predict the fault I could have committed.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package me.thirumurugan.quiz;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button submit;
    TextView result;
    RadioButton answer_a;
    EditText answer_b;
    CheckBox answer_c1, answer_c2, answer_c3, answer_c4;
    EditText answer_d;
    int correct = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        answer_a = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.answer_a);
        answer_b = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer_b);
        answer_c1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.answer_c1);
        answer_c2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.answer_c2);
        answer_c3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.answer_c3);
        answer_c4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.answer_c4);
        answer_d = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer_d);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                correct = 0;
                if (answer_a.isChecked()){
                    correct++;
                }
                if (answer_b.getText().toString().equals("2020")){
                    correct++;
                }
                if (answer_c1.isChecked()&&answer_c2.isChecked()&&answer_c3.isChecked()&&!answer_c4.isChecked()){
                    correct++;
                }
                if (answer_d.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals("arun jaitley")){
                    correct++;
                }
                result.setText("The Score is " + correct + " on 4!");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="me.thirumurugan.quiz.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/welcome_messege"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="#FFF"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding"
                android:text="@string/question_1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/answer_a"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/answer_1_a" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/answer_1_b" />

            </RadioGroup>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding"
                android:text="@string/question_2"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/answer_b"
                android:hint="@string/answer_hint"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding"
                android:text="@string/question_3"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/answer_c1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/answer_3_a" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/answer_c2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/answer_3_b" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/answer_c3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/answer_3_c" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/answer_c4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/answer_3_d" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding"
                android:text="@string/question_4"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/answer_d"
                android:hint="@string/answer_hint"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/submit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="@string/submit"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The error message was the following in the trace:

> 08-10 21:58:06.301 20947-20947/me.thirumurugan.quiz E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main  Process: me.thirumurugan.quiz, PID: 20947
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference at
>   me.thirumurugan.quiz.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52) at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: i just copied your code and pasted in my android studio and it work just fine no error

Comment: try to clean and build your app , and also use break point  to debug your app

Comment: I agree with Ali, nothing here looks broken.  You should do a clean and build.

Comment: No, didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You are in need of a clean and rebuild.  There is nothing wrong with your code.  Multiple users have copied the code and used it to success in their applications, including myself:

[image]

Text is missing because I do not have your dimens or strings files.

You do not have a scope issue, as others have suggested.  Your member variables should be accessible by any anonymous inner class you create.

There are otherwise missing lines from your shared code.  In which case, the community can not resolve your problem as nobody will be capable of replicating it.